# Error 4673 audit failure filling security logs

Tags: windows, authentication, security

I have an isolated desktop computer in my office that I run weekly security audits on. I check the logs for odd behavior then export and clear them out.

The logs are *filled* with "Audit failure Microsoft Windows Security Auditing Event ID 4673"

> A privileged service was called
>
> Subject:
>
> ```
>  Security ID:          System
>
>  Account Name:         Standalone_System_2$
>
>  Account Domain:       WORKGROUP
>
>  Logon ID:             0x307
> ```
>
> Service:
>
> ```
>  Server:               Security Account Manager
>
>  Service Name:         Security Account Manager
> ```
>
> Process:
>
> ```
>  Process ID:           0x208
>
>  Process Name:         C:\Windows\System32\lsass.ese
> ```
>
> Service Request Information:
>
> ```
>  Privileges:           SeTcbPrivilege
> ```

I found [this Technet post](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/38c1ce35-7d90-4cd7-991a-eaafee6f748d/lsassexe-permissions-issue) which advised that I turn off "Audit Privilege Use"... Not the route I need to take.

Some have suggested that it could be the antivirus causing these log entries... I'm not sure how to identify the offending account or service. I checked services on the system and I see a service named "Security **Accounts** Manager", however this service is *not* named "Security **Account** Manager".

Not sure where to go but I want to get this audit log under control! All these useless entries make it nearly impossible to find actual events.

Answer (score 2):

The last entry on this thread talks about using a specific tool to determine the user in question for this error (Login ID is unique since boot, but after a reboot changes so you need to see what account is connected to this request) and validate whether they should have permissions to do what they are attmepting:  http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_xp-security/577-many-failures-pertaining-to-setcbprivilege-in/3944f31c-dda4-46d9-adbf-74a9953dedeb

Reproduced here because the forum is a bit hard to read:

> I noticed that I was getting a BUNCH of these from LSASS. (like about 17k in ~ 2 hours... couldn't figure out why the event logger was requiring so much I/O... (it was logging alot of fails)...SeTCBPriv fails.
>
> I used 'process hacker2', (a sup'ed up version of process explorer, now that procexp is controlled by MS, (sorta like letting the foxes own your tools for watching fox in your hen-house!)..
>
> Then I could look at what account lsass(samss)  was using to run under.(either in services or in process hacker2 -- on sourceforge.net, BTW).
>
> Then using the Local security policy panel in the admin tools, and looking under the "User Rights Assignment", I could make sure all of the required privileges needed to run, (as stated on the service ACL were permitted (if they aren't, it won't run, so that's usually not an issue), BUT, ALSO make sure the account LSASS was running under had the "Act as part of the operating system' (trusted computing base/tcb) privilege.
>
> Same goes for any other Service -- that is generating lots of audit fails... verify it has the privileges it needs on its ACL (something incredibly cryptic to do w/o a GUI...).  If you aren't sure.... research it on the net and see if it should have that priv..if it is signed and certified by  MS, then likely your system is misconfigured (at least from that service's perspective ;-))  Then you just need to give it the privs it needs -- ALSO a neat thing in PH2, you can just click an option as to whether or not the service runs with a bunch of other services or not.  So far, have been
>   been able to split out interactive stuff (audio/video/desktop) from background services so I could effectively prioritize them -- before this recent discovery, no way of turning down priority on some lower prior services w/o affecting audio and/or desktop...
>
> Anyway, after making sure LSASS had the tcb privs.. the messages went away...

Answer (score 2):

I know this is old, but if you are using any Domain Isolation with IPSec, you will get hundreds of thousands of successful 4673 events from lsass.exe.  Why MS did this is beyond me. They recommend for high security environments to have both "Audit Sensitive Privilege Use" enabled for failure and success and also to use IPSec.  Can't have both if you want any sort of security logs last longer than a day even with the max 4gb security log size.

Someone slap MS up the side of the head for this one.

Comment: Welcome to Server Fault! Your answer currently does not seem to provide a workable solution to the question and might be more appropriate as a comment or even just an upvote. Please read [How do I write a good answer?](http://serverfault.com/help/how-to-answer) and consider revising or deleting your current answer. And don't forget to take the [site tour](http://serverfault.com/tour).

Answer (score 0):

I've been trying to get a handle on this for years. MS Learn articles say to monitor success/failure, and in the same breath, to not monitor bc of the high volume. I found details about SePrivileges in Windows Forensics by Carvey. ChatGPT gives a good conversation on it. I found a couple new articles below. ProcessHacker gave some insight to the tokens requested. TMX might help. Further tools for wininternals like:

"The source of SeTcbPrivilege is from a call to ImportantFileWriter::WriteFileAtomically, which results in a call to the Windows ReplaceFile which calls NtSetSecurityObject which results in the privilege check."

I get 4673 with all browsers. Sandbox, Updates, telemetry? Makes sense it would check for system-level perms. VirusTotal will show  site's permission requests. I used procmon to filter the process and not successful entries.
-browser | used chrome taskmgr to get process id and linked to blocking extensions.
-onedrive | possible old SIDs from reimages.

It seems like MS made a worthless privilege audit back in the day. I think Dave's Garage on YT said MS only intended event logs for the system's reference, and Randy Smith said the event viewer wasn't meant to be a real solution. Since even the Chromium devs dismissed it, I think the concenus is to not audit it unless you're in a critical org that needs to keep it. I suppose it could be good to get a baseline and enable after an incident to monitor.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/security/threat-protection/auditing/audit-sensitive-privilege-use

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/security/threat-protection/auditing/event-4673#security-monitoring-recommendations

[Error 4673 audit failure filling security logs](https://serverfault.com/questions/589753/error-4673-audit-failure-filling-security-logs?newreg=1601184137b84becafca1511286e9158)

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/msdn-technet-forums/38c1ce35-7d90-4cd7-991a-eaafee6f748d

https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_xp-security/577-many-failures-pertaining-to-setcbprivilege-in/3944f31c-dda4-46d9-adbf-74a9953dedeb